# A way to make JavaScript style changes happen before css is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So on my websites I need to make sure that everything still works even when JavaScript is being blocked, which means that things that I want to hide until someone clicks on something have to be shown with CSS and then hidden with JS, which makes it look glitchy when the page is loading because the JS files are always loaded after the CSS stylesheets.

Is there a way for JS style changes to happen before CSS is loaded? Like, stop the CSS from loading with JS, make the necessary changes, and then continue loading the other files, maybe?

Comment: if javascript is disabled, how do you expect to use it?

Comment: _"I need to make sure that everything still works even when JavaScript is being blocked"_ Why?

Comment: Have you tried loading the stylesheets with javascript? Then you can do this whenever you desire to.

Comment: Have you tried just loading the JS first?

Comment: Search the net for FOUC and see what they say to do.

Comment: Have a certain CSS, then use JS to load a different CSS file overwritting the original, which will make it work for both cases.

Comment: @Griffin uhm, I don't. I expect the website to be usable when the JS is disabled. A website doesn't need JS to work.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter because I like to make good websites which everyone can use? I only use JS for some design tweaks and animations, not for actual functionality.

Comment: @Cruiser yes and it's not loaded at all that way

Comment: @SuzanneEdelmanCreoconcept if it's just  small changes, you may well want to just use the <noscript> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `.js-enabled`  class to HTML the tag with an inline script at the top of the head tag. You can then have CSS hide the scripted stuff for you while the rest of the scripts load.

Comment: I actually added a class to the body tag and called all js files right after it, first thing in the first file is to remove the class and then I just use css to hide it when the class doesnt exist and show it when it does. Then i added $(document).ready() to all other JS so that it still gets called as soon as the dom's ready (because the js functions weren't happening at all without this)

Comment: I got the idea from you which is why i marked this as the answer. thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to load your css-file after some code of your javascript:
1. Don't specify a href attribute of you css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="screen" id="my-style">
```

2. Add this in your code (may be the last line of your javascript):

   $('#my-style').attr('href','style.css');

And your css-file will be loaded only after that line of javascript

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer (see comment below):

If JS is blocked, you need to either choose to detect this and serve content based on that, meaning backend code, or make use of another strategy such as `<noscript>`.

Original answer:

> which means that things that I want to hide until someone clicks on something have to be shown with CSS and then hidden with JS,

I would always start with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` (see elsewhere for difference between the two) in the css, and use the JS to reveal the element.

Comment: Note I wrote "So on my websites I need to make sure that everything still works even when JavaScript is being blocked" so what you're suggesting won't solve the problem.

Comment: if it's blocked its blocked. I'm updating my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve your problem. What you need to know is the difference between blocking and non-blocking content. Every script and css (media=screen) is immediately invoked. So if you put some css in there in your head, and append something with JavaScript later on, you indeed might seen it shortly in a 'non javascript' way.

To combat this you could have the objects initial state represent the html/css as if the JavaScript has been loaded. (Most ideally you would have serverside rendering, but for simpler sites thing isn't always needed). The downside of this method is that if you have an JavaScript error which prevents further execution, you have a broken state. And if you also neglect the few people that have JS disabled, you're save and rendering looks fine again. Furthermore! You can improve on your sites performance by loading the scripts asynchronously.

If you want a different approach, you can add a className to your html eg `<html class="noscript">`. Then when all your JavaScript has been loaded, you remove the className. This way you only have one redraw, and it looks progressive. There is a downside to this approach though, since bad performance becomes increasingly visible (since the first time your browser rendered and the time the JavaScript is done could take a while). So ussually this method is not preferred (though looks better than the first for non-js/js disabled browsers).